# Delete body removed by zuul

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I know that ZUUL removes the request body for DELETE method. I have a situation in which I can't change the API contract. Therefore I want help in this case to identify an alternative approach in which I can do some manipulation on Zuul side.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked directly with Zuul before, but one option I have used in the past for similar situations was to place the delete body into the HTTP header, assuming it would fit and make good sense to do that.  Then, assuming Zuul does not strip the header, you could just extract the body data from there.

The alternative, perhaps the best approach, would be to change the behavior of Zuul.  But, there might be open source licensing issues if you change the Zuul codebase.